# How to link a directory to Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to link a directory to a Visual Studio solution?

Don't get me wrong: I don't want to use a *Solution Folder*. I want to add/link a "real" directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into **Project** -> **Add existing item**, then mark all the files from the directory you want to link,  and select the second dropdown under **Add** (***Add as link***), you should be good. 
Personal experience has shown me however that with this solution, if you add or delete files from your directory you'll have to manually adjust for those changes in Visual Studio, or your solution will not pick up on the new files/crash.